# Play Framework can't connect to WS

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4

i am trying to offer a WebSocket connection to my Play app, however I am encountering problems even with the example code.
Using the websocket echo page, I try to send data. However, I can't even connect.

I have a controller where I have the sample `public WebSocket<String> socket()`
In my routes file I have `GET /socket  @controllers.Application.socket()`

When using the URL: ws://localhost:9001/socket nothing happens
When using wss://localhost:9001/socket, I get netty errors with no real information.

```
[error] p.c.s.n.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: ???  ?+?/???????
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:94) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:191) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:102) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[error] p.c.s.n.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: ???  ?+?/???????
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:94) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:191) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:102) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.cleanup(ReplayingDecoder.java:554) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelDisconnected(FrameDecoder.java:365) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:102) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[error] p.c.s.n.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: Z#  "?+?/ ????????
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:94) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:191) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:102) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[error] p.c.s.n.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: Z#  "?+?/ ????????
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:94) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:191) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:102) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.cleanup(ReplayingDecoder.java:554) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelDisconnected(FrameDecoder.java:365) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:102) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[error] p.c.s.n.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:89) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:191) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:102) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[error] p.c.s.n.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:89) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:191) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:102) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.cleanup(ReplayingDecoder.java:554) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelDisconnected(FrameDecoder.java:365) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:102) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[error] p.c.s.n.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:89) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:191) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:102) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
[error] p.c.s.n.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:89) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:191) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:102) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.cleanup(ReplayingDecoder.java:554) ~[netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelDisconnected(FrameDecoder.java:365) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:102) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.3.Final.jar:na]
```

I sadly don't know what to do. I can offer more code if needed, by it is the example code from Play's documentation page.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was because I was using the echo test in HTTPS. Once I changed it to HTTP everything worked.